# How to calculate the intersection of two hyperplanes in MATLAB?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Assume you have two affine spaces defined as follows:

$$S_1:  v^{*} + \sum \alpha_i \hat{v}_{i}$$

where $v^{*}$ is a vector in $R^n$ and $\alpha$'s are coefficients and $\hat{v}$'s are basis vectors for spanning.

and the second space is defined similarly

$S_1:  u^{*} + \sum \beta_j \hat{u}_{i}$

So the question is, how to calculate the intersection of the two spaces in MATLAB. I know how to calculate it by hand: just set $S_1=S_2$ and derive some relationships for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

The solution (or let's say the output of the matlab script) should be the intersection basis. That is,

$S_1\bigcap S_2 : z^{*} + \sum \gamma_k\hat{z}_k$.

So the output is vectors $z^{*}$ and $\hat{z}_k$. Of course it is not unique.

---

Let me make it absolutely clear. Here's an example:

$S_1 :  \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     1\\
    1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)+ \alpha_1\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     2\\
     1\\
  \end{array}
\right)+\alpha_2 \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     1\\
     2\\
  \end{array}
\right)$.

And

$S_2 :  \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     0\\
     0\\
    1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)+ \beta_1\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     0\\
     1\\
     1\\
  \end{array}
\right)+\beta_2 \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     0\\
     1\\
  \end{array}
\right)$.

Basically two planes, so the intersection would be a line. 
And when I work out (on paper!) I come up with the intersection (after row-elimination) :

$S_1\bigcap S_2 : \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     0\\
     2\\
  \end{array}
\right)+ \gamma_1 \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     1\\
     2\\
  \end{array}
\right)$.

How can you do the whole procedure automatically in Matlab?

Comment: Create a matrix formulation of your solution process. The componenets of the basis vectors will form the elements of your matrices and your unknowns will involve $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s. Your solutions  will have some parameters in them so you will need to work symbolically.

Comment: @Paul that's exactly the procedure. But how to write it to matlab (or basically the algorithm) is the question. I mean the part to handle the parametric solution.

Comment: We expect to get the solution in the following easy form. something like:  $S_1\bigcap S_2 : z^{*} + \sum \gamma_k\hat{z}_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let U, V be the $n \times (n-1)$ matrices of the spanning vectors of $S_1$ and $S_2$ and let u0, v0 be the particular vectors that are also given. You can find a particular vector z0 in the intersection with the Matlab command

z0 = [U,V]*([U,V]\(v0 - u0))

and you can get a $n \times (n-2)$ matrix of spanning vectors of the intersection with the command

Z = null([null(U),null(V)]) .

Comment: your proposal seems promising but unfortunately didn't work when I tried. Note that my spaces are affine so there's a shift by $v^*$ ( and $u^*$). And what are the spanning vectors you mean? Do you mean $\hat{v}_k$'s (and $\hat{u}_k$'s)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something similar to bellow

```
    s1 = [1 1; 2 1; 1 2;];
    s1 = s1';
    n1 = null(s1);
    x1 = [1; 1; 1];

    s2 = [ 0  1; 1 0; 1 1;];
    s2 = s2';
    n2 = null(s2);
    x2 = [0; 0; 1];


    drawVector(n1, {'n1'});
    hold on 
    drawSpan(s1', 'r');

    drawVector(n2, {'n2'});
    drawSpan(s2', 'r');

    n3 = null([n1 n2]')
    drawVector(n3, {'n3'});
```

[image]

For visualization, I used: [drawLA](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23608-drawla-draw-toolbox-for-linear-algebra)